# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} \:= \:\frac{Ay}{By \:+ \:C} \:+ \:DP \:- \:EPy\:$ for $\:P$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In the equation, $y\:$ is the dependent variable and $\:x\:$ is the independent variable. $\:A, \:B, \:C, \:D, \:E,\:$ and $\:P\:$ are constants. How can we find an optimum value for $\:P\:$ given the boundary conditions for $\:x\:$ and $\:y:$ $\:(x_0,y_0), \:(x_1,y_1)$?

My solution:

$\frac{dy}{dx} \:= \:\frac{Ay}{By \:+ \:C} \:+ \:DP \:- \:EPy$

$\implies dy\:\frac{B \:+ \:Cy}{Ay \:+ \:PBD \:- \:PEBy \:+ \:PCDy \:- \:PECy^2} \:= \:dx$

$\implies dy\:\frac{B \:+ \:Cy}{PBD \:+ \:(A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD)y \:- \:PECy^2} \:= \:dx$

Equate $\:BD \:+ \:(A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD)y \:- \:PECy^2\:$ with $\:ay^2 \:+ \:by \:+ \:c$,

$\therefore \:a \:= \:- \:PEC$, $\:b \:= \:A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD\:$ and $\:c \:= \:PBD$

Let $\:k_1\:$ and $\:k_2\:$ be the roots of $\:ay^2 \:+ \:by \:+ c \:= \:0$,

$\therefore \:k_1,k_2 \:= \:\frac{- \:b \:\pm \:\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\:$ where $\:\Delta \:= \:b^2 \:- \:4ac$

$\frac{B \:+ \:Cy}{PBD \:+ \:(A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD)y \:- \:PECy^2} \:= \:\frac{u}{y \:- \:k_1} \:+ \:\frac{v}{y \:- \:k_2}$

$\implies\frac{B \:+ \:Cy}{PBD \:+ \:(A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD)y \:- \:PECy^2} \:= \:\frac{u (y \:- \:k_2) \:+ \:v (y \:- \:k_1)}{(y \:- \:k_1)\:(y \:- \:k_2)}$

$\implies\frac{B \:+ \:Cy}{PBD \:+ \:(A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD)y \:- \:PECy^2} \:= \:\frac{(- \:k_2 u \:- \:k_1 v) \:+ \:(u \:+ \:v)y}{(y \:- \:k_1)\:(y \:- \:k_2)}$

$\therefore u \:+ \:v \:= \:C\:$ and $\:- \:k_2 u \:- \:k_1 v \:= \:B$

which results to $\:u \:= \:\frac{B \:+ \:C k_1}{k_2 \:- \:k_1}\:$ and $\:v \:= \:\frac{B \:+ \:C k_2}{k_1 \:- \:k_2}$

$\therefore dy\:(\frac{B \:+ \:Cy}{PBD \:+ \:(A \:- \:PEB \:+ \:PCD)y \:- \:PECy^2}) \:= \:dx\:$ becomes $\:dy\:(\frac{B \:+ \:C k_1}{(k_1 \:- \:k_2)\:(y \:- \:k_1)} \:- \:\frac{B \:+ \:C k_2}{(k_1 \:- \:k_2)\:(y \:- \:k_2)}) \:= \:dx$

On integration,

$\frac{B \:+ \:C  k_1}{k_1 \:- \:k_2}\:\ln(y \:- \:k_1) \:- \:\frac{B \:+ \:C k_2}{k_1 \:- \:k_2}\:\ln(y \:- \:k_2) \:= \:x \:+ \:constant$

We remove the constant term by putting in the boundary conditions and then solve the resulting equation numerically with methods like Newton-Raphson.

**Problem**: I keep getting garbage values for P when I use this method with a bad initial guess. On using a near-correct guess, I get either of $\:k_1\:$ or $\:k_2\:$ equal to $\:y_1\:$ which gives a division by $\:0\:$ error.

Comment: "Garbage values", hey no need to be rude to the values :(

Comment: Btw how are you defining optimum value for $P$?

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai haha, I meant garbage in a computer programming sort of way. Optimum values for P would be the ones that if used to solve the ODE with the initial boundary condition $(x_0,y_0)$ would yield final boundary values near $(x_1,y_1)$.